# Swagger UI is rendered incorrectly after upgrading Springfox from 2.x to 3.0.0

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox, springfox-boot-starter

I am working on a Spring Boot 2.2.x application. I have upgraded the Springfox version from 2.5.x to 3.0.0 by following these instructions:
[migration from 2.x to 3.0.0](https://github.com/springfox/springfox)

Swagger/Springfox configuration:

```java
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
     return new ApiInfo(“Api”,”1.0”,swaggerdoc(), new Contact(“Name”,”Url”,”email”),””,””,Collections.emptyList());

}

private String swaggerDoc() {
     return “<Html and css as string>”
}
```

In Swagger UI generated by Springfox 2.5.x I can see that the style tags in CSS are working as expected. But with Springfox 3.0.0, I can see the page is not loading the CSS files and thus displaying most of the HTML as text.

[image]

Any thoughts on why CSS is not coming into the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are no css and jquery libraries included in the latest version (springfox 3.0.0). We need to customize the /index.html call for localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ in order to add additinonal styling and to include jquery.